# Error connecting to exchange server remotely via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to connect to my Exchange server remotely using PowerShell. The Exchange server is on its own dedicated Exchange forest. I am trying to open the connection on a forest that does not have the Exchange server.

This is what I have in my PowerShell script:

```
$powershell_url = "http://exhange_server_url.com/PowerShell/"
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $powershell_url -Authentication Kerberos
```

When I run this script, I get this error:

> [exhange_server_url.com] Connecting to
>   remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM
>   client cannot process the request. The authentication mechanism
>   requested by the client is not supported by  the server or unencrypted
>   traffic is disabled in the service configuration. Verify the
>   unencrypted traffic setting in the service configuration or specify
>   one of the authentication mechanisms supported by the server.  To use
>   Kerberos, sp ecify the computer name as the remote destination. Also
>   verify that the client computer and the destination computer ar e
>   joined to a domain. To use Basic, specify the computer name as the
>   remote destination, specify Basic authentication a nd provide user
>   name and password. Possible authentication mechanisms reported by
>   server: For more information, see the  about_Remote_Troubleshooting
>   Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [],
>   PSRemotingTransportExc    eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "DOMAIN\Administrator","password"
#connect with remote cas server
$powershell_url = "http://cas-server/PowerShell/"
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $powershell_url  -credential $credentials -Authentication Kerberos
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your account is enabled for Remote Exchange?

Here is a site for more information:[Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298084.aspx)

Comment: Yes, the account is enabled for remote access.